# Guardar función en un map C++

Tags: c++

Tengo una clase `Token`

```cpp
class Token {
private:
    string valor;
public:
    Token();
    Token(string valor_): valor(valor_) {}
    string getValor(){ return valor; }
};
```

Y tengo una función

```cpp
Token imprimir(vector<Token>, string, string);

Token imprimir(vector<Token> args, string end = "\n", string sep = " "){
    Token i;
    for(auto i: args) cout << i.getValor() << sep;
    cout << end;
    return Token(string("NADA"));
```

Por ahora solo tengo esa función, pero luego tendré más y quiero guardar esas funciones en un `std::map` para luego poder buscar la función y usarla cuando requiera. Había hecho esto:

```cpp
template <typename ...T>
map<string, Token(*)(T...)> mis_funciones;
mis_funciones["imprimir"] = imprimir;
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
argument list for variable template "mis_funciones" is missing
```

Traté de "solucionarlo" e hice esto:

```cpp
template <typename ...T>
map<string, Token(*)(T...)> mis_funciones = {
    { "imprimir", imprimir}
};
```

Pero si quiero acceder a este elemento obtengo nuevamenete el mismo error

```cpp
mis_funciones["imprimir"];

//error
// argument list for variable template "mis_funciones" is missing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una plantilla solo existe en el código fuente. Lo que vive en el ejecutable son las instancias de las plantillas.

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código, la función `test` no existe.

```
template <typename T>
void test(T a) {
    ...
}

int main(){
    test<int>(1);
    test<bool>(true);
    test<float>(1.0);
}
```

Lo que hace el compilador es generar código a partir de la plantilla. Algo así, donde no hay plantillas y sí es claro que las funciones van a ser parte del ejecutable (sin tener en cuenta que sean estén vacías u optimizaciones):

```
void test(int a) { // instancia
    ...
}
void test(bool a) { // instancia
    ...
}
void test(float a) { // instancia
    ...
}

int main(){
    test<int>(1);
    test<bool>(true);
    test<float>(1.0);
}
```

---

Lo mismo aplica a tu código, `mis_funciones` es una plantilla por lo tanto no existe la variable `mis_funciones`.

Si miras el [código ensamblador](https://godbolt.org/z/89cdjefrd) que genera un código fuente como este:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

template <typename ...T>
map<string, int(*)(T...)> mis_funciones;

int test(int a, int b) {
    return 0;
}

int test(int a) {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    mis_funciones<int, int>["test"] = test;
    mis_funciones<int>["test"] = test;
}
```

Verás que `mis_funciones<int, int>` y `mis_funciones<int>` son variables (e instancias de la plantilla) diferentes.

Por cierto, el error que te marca el compilador es que no puede inferir los parámetros así que necesitas indicarlo:

```
mis_funciones<int>["test"]
             ^^^^^
```